# Add Images into DataSet - VB.Net SOAP Web Service

Tags: vb.net, soap, dataset, tiff

Modifying an old program, it stored images(.TIF) in a database, due to file sizes growing I am trying to pull the images off a file share instead of storing them all in the database going forward.  I made a test bit of code for just .TIF filetypes so far, but the images are not being sent back in the dataset.  I am trying to modify the SOAP Web Service so that this change will not affect clients using the software.  Here is what I have:

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function GetSerialNumbers() As DataSet

    Dim daSerialNumbers As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  Order_No, Serial_Range, Serial_Numbers, Pages, Notes,SequenceId  FROM SerialNumbers where   Order_No like  '" & SN & "' ORDER BY Order_No, Pages", cnSerialNumbers)
    Dim dsSerialNumbers As New DataSet

    daSerialNumbers.Fill(dsSerialNumbers, "SerialNumbers")

    For i = 0 To dsSerialNumbers.Tables("SerialNumbers").Rows.Count - 1
        If dsSerialNumbers.Tables("SerialNumbers").Rows(i).Item("Pages").ToString.Contains(".TIF") Then
            Dim newImage As System.Drawing.Image = Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\temp\660-50369.tif")
            dsSerialNumbers.Tables("SerialNumbers").Rows(i).Item("Contents").value = ImageToPictureArray(newImage)
        End If
    Next

    Return dsSerialNumbers
End Function


Public Function ImageToPictureArray(ByVal picImage As System.Drawing.Image) As Byte()
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    picImage.Save(ms, picImage.RawFormat)
    Dim arrImage() As Byte = ms.GetBuffer
    ms.Close()
    Return arrImage
End Function
```

This is the old code, definitely a lot simpler to just load from a sql database...

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function GetSerialNumbers() As DataSet
    Dim daSerialNumbers As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  Order_No, Serial_Range, Serial_Numbers, Pages, Notes, Contents,SequenceId  FROM SerialNumbers3 where   Order_No like  '" & SN & "' ORDER BY Order_No, Pages", cnSerialNumbers)
    Dim dsSerialNumbers As New DataSet
    daSerialNumbers.Fill(dsSerialNumbers, "SerialNumbers")
    Return dsSerialNumbers
End Function
```

Comment: Instead of reading a file in as an Image, writing it it to a memorystream as Raw(i.e. what type of file it is natively) then turn the stream into a byte, you can just read the file into a Byte() with e.g. System.Io.File.ReadAllBytes()..

Comment: Show us the old code that worked too

Comment: Uploaded the old code as well.

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for the tip on System.Io.File.ReadAllBytes().  That helped shorten my code significantly.  I figured out what was happening.  When I moved the table in SQL and stripped all the images out of the Contents column I recreated it as an VARCHAR(50) instead of IMAGE data type.  Once I changed the database back to an image datatype all the images started coming though fine.  I would like to just get rid of that field later as I know image is now depreciated.  But I will attempt to do that and seek help when I get there if need be.

Comment: Store the path to the image in the db? Eventually transition to sending the url to the user rather than loading the bytes into the dataset and sending them (then put the images on a cdn).. evolutions!

Comment: PPS: read http://bobby-tables.com